# config.xml formatting problem

Tags: android, xml, permissions, cordova, config

I am trying to prevent an android application from requesting lots of pemissions and I am developing using phonegap. I asked a question here:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/change_android_permissions_none_required

The advice I was given was to add this line to my config.xml file:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

I have done this but the app still requests 7 permissions at install. Below is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = ""
xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id = "com.sapps.reftorange"
version = "1.0.0">
<name>Test</name>

<gap:platforms>
<gap:platform name="android" minVersion="1.0" />
</gap:platforms>
<icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />

<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>


</widget>
```

Is there something I'm missing with this or do you think my problem lies elsewhere?

EDIT: Second line now reads

```
 <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
```

And the app now requests 3 permissons, these being phone calls, network and storage. It would be my guess that the

```
 <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

tag doesn't actually remove all permission requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the line above, although downloading from phonegap and installing still requests 3 permissions, uploading to the android market and then downloading to a device asks for internet only which was the goal. Turns out the phonegap guys got it right! Hope this helps anyone in my situation.